# 2021 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

### The 2021 Community Moderator Election has now started!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/5

for more detail, and to participate!

Also, click the nomination button to read the comments and candidates' responses.

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).